# Adding Mobile Number based login mechanism for auth user in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Can we implement Firebase for an android app, where I am registering user using Mobile number (Similar to Whatsapp). Users will be sent a code by server which is entered by user in android app to validate the user mobile number and registering him on the server.

Question : Can I use the above method in conjunction with Firebase Auth?

I was earlier going to use MongoDB for my project, but since Firebase has SYNC capabilities, it will be a better choice for storing data. Another good reason is as below:

> If a client loses its network connection, your app will continue
>   functioning correctly.
>
> Every client connected to a Firebase database maintains its own
>   internal version of any active data. When data is written, it's
>   written to this local version first. The Firebase client then
>   synchronizes that data with the remote database servers and with other
>   clients on a "best-effort" basis.

Very NEW to Firebase, just came to know about firebase (through Google 2016 IO). 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Comment: Solutions like these will cost you money.

Comment: @Devprashant we have already purchases SMS API from service provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebase hosting is not for server side processing.**

It stores static assets of your website as a world-class high availability CDN. So websites hosted here loads very fast. Even in high-availability scenarios.

So you have to do processing at other server which then connects with firebase and stores userinfo in realtime database.

Firebase has put limits on userinfo to be placed in directly for users auth dashboard.
For detailed userinfo, firebase realtime db is the way to go(from your processing backend to firebase realtime db).

Further Reading: [What kind of web applications are Firebase not ideal for?](https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-web-applications-are-Firebase-not-ideal-for/answer/Manav-Sehgal-2?srid=TVuO)